# Why typescript recognizes imported variables as of type any?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, import, export

I have the following 2 files:

File `src/helpers.ts`:

```js
const someHelperArray = ['value1', 'value2'] as const

module.exports = {
  someHelperArray
}
```

File `src/car.ts`:

```js
const {
  someHelperArray
} = require('./helpers')
```

In the file `car.ts` when I hover over the `someHelperArray` I get this typescript type resolution: `const someHelperArray: any` instead of literal type I expected (`'value1' | 'value2'`). Essentially typescript doesn't recognize the types of imported variables from another file. I tried changing `tsconfig.json` settings but nothing helped. How to can I get typescript to recognize types imported from other files?

This is my `tsconfig.ts`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": ["dom", "es6", "scripthost", "esnext"],
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "baseUrl": "src",
      "watch": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "inlineSources": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "ts-out/**/*", "babel-out/**/*"]
  }
```

Comment: Once I refactored the code to use ES6 syntax for modules import/export the issue was disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CommonJS module (with `require`) is not statically analyzable, which means the content of `module` is unknown before run time. Indeed, you could write any kind of dynamic code to assign it (i.e: `Object.assign`). So if you need to retain the types between modules you have to write them as ES6 modules because these are statically analyzable. Note that it is supported in latest versions of Node.js only.

If you wanted to keep using CommonJS modules in the source code, you could also have one file `src/helpers.js`:

```
const someHelperArray = ['value1', 'value2'];

module.exports = {
  someHelperArray
}
```

And one `src/helpers.d.ts` like this:

```
export const someHelperArray: ['value1', 'value2'];
```